# Facebook Graph API /me/accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API v18.0

Problem: /me/accounts is returning an empty data: [].

I created an Facebook app having Facebook Login and Instagram Graph API as products.

I then went to Graph API Explorer and added as a permissions...

```
'instagram_basic',
'instagram_content_publish',
'instagram_manage_comments',
'instagram_manage_insights',
'pages_show_list',
'public_profile',
'pages_read_engagement',
```

I logged in as myself and generated an access token. During the login process, I confirmed my Facebook page and my Instagram account (professional and linked to the Facebook page. Using the Access Token Debugger, I know that these permissions exist on the token. They also exist as granted when I call /me/permissions.

But when I call /me/accounts, it returns only an empty data: [] array.

I confirm I appear as Administrator role in the Facebook app under App roles.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

This has appeared before on Stack overflow but with previous versions of the Graph API.

Comment: If the page is a business page, then you will need the `business_management` permission as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts#permissions